# Total count for each month; but month gives duplicate entries; even with distinct keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select statement

```
select distinct month(orderdate) AS [Mon]
     , count(orderid) as [Cnt] 
  from Orders where orderdate >= x and orderdate < y
```

that returns results like

```
Mon   Cnt
1     1
1     2
2     4
2     3
3     2
4     1
```

How do I get the results for each month?

```
Mon   Cnt
1     3
2     7
3     2
4     1
```

Comment: Sample data and table structure would go a long way to making this answerable. As it sits right now, nobody can help you because there isn't enough information.

Comment: Thanks John. The formatting was so rough I didn't even notice they did in fact post sample data.

Comment: There is no sample data just wanted results and actual results

Comment: There are, in fact, no "duplicate" rows; each row has a different value in either the `Mon` or `Cnt` columns. That query, however, would never work in SQL Server, it lacks a `GROUP BY` which would cause an error due to the aggregate function. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3JkoYHke) Are you sure you're using SQL Server? Also a `DISTINCT` with an aggregate query never makes sense; the `GROUP BY` (which *must* be there for a result) would already return the data in *distinct* sets.

Comment: I think it's worth calling out the disconnect with what `DISTINCT` does, and what the OP expected.
`DISTINCT` will return only rows where the values are distinct - but that does mean the entire row. Had there been two rows each returning 1,1 it would have only returned one row. I think the OP expected some level of aggregation to happen by their use of `DISTINCT`.

Comment: You seem to want a sum rather than a count.

Answer (score 1):

You want to count the number of orders by month.  You need to group by the month.

so something like this:

```
select month(orderdate) as mon,  count(distinct orderid) as order_count
from Orders
where orderdate >= x and orderdate < y
group by month(orderdate)
```

bonus::

You can also get this value when you don't use group by with a windowing function -- like this:

```
 select -- whatever
       count(orderid) over (partition by month(orderdate)) as order_count
 from orders
```

Comment: The latter query isn't valid T-SQL. You can't just put a `PARTITION BY` in without a windowed aggregate being defined, and a `COUNT(DISTINCT)` can't be windowed. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LHxh1qeX)

Comment: @ThomA -- good point -- I was late for a meeting a wrote it fast, I fixed the incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you're looking for:

```
SELECT DATEPART(MONTH,InvoiceDateTimeUTC), COUNT(InvoiceID)
  FROM Invoices
 WHERE InvoiceDateTimeUTC >= '2023-01-01' 
   AND InvoiceDateTimeUTC < '2023-04-30 23:59:59.997'
 GROUP BY DATEPART(MONTH,InvoiceDateTimeUTC)
```

| Month | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 4323 |
| 1 | 4161 |
| 4 | 4144 |
| 2 | 3848 |

You didn't provide any example DDL, or DML, so I used a demo table I already had. The column names are pretty self explanatory and should be easy to map to your own.

All we're doing here is counting the number of rows for each month.

There are some pitfalls to be aware of here. If your date range is ever extended beyond a year, you won't know which year the data belongs to. It's probably a good idea to also include that. You can use `DATEPART(YEAR,InvoiceDateTimeUTC)` to return that. It would also need to be in the group clause.

I also want to talk about why DISTINCT didn't do what you expected it to. It returns distinct rows - where each row is different from the others.

Consider:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (Month INT, Count INT);
INSERT INTO @Table (Month, Count) VALUES (1,1),(2,1),(1,1),(1,2);

SELECT *
  FROM @Table
```

| Month | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |

Now if we apply DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM @Table
```

| Month | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |

Only a single 1,1 row is returned. `DISTINCT` removed the duplicate, and that's it.